# Installing MySQL-Service on Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I just installed Ubuntu 15.04. Also installed xampp and now I am trying to install mysql-service to use the mysql commands (imports, exports etc). I ran this command sudo apt-get install mysql-service and I got this error.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libdbd-mysql-perl libmysqlclient18 mysql-client-5.6 mysql-common
  mysql-server-5.6
Suggested packages:
  mailx tinyca
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libdbd-mysql-perl libmysqlclient18 mysql-client-5.6 mysql-common
  mysql-server mysql-server-5.6
0 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/11,6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 104 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-common.
(Reading database ... 210291 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-common_5.6.28-0ubuntu0.15.10.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-common (5.6.28-0ubuntu0.15.10.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libmysqlclient18:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libmysqlclient18_5.6.28-0ubuntu0.15.10.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libmysqlclient18:amd64 (5.6.28-0ubuntu0.15.10.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libdbd-mysql-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libdbd-mysql-perl_4.028-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libdbd-mysql-perl (4.028-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-client-5.6.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-client-5.6_5.6.28-0ubuntu0.15.10.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-client-5.6 (5.6.28-0ubuntu0.15.10.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.4-1) ...
Setting up mysql-common (5.6.28-0ubuntu0.15.10.1) ...
update-alternatives: using /etc/mysql/my.cnf.fallback to provide /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my.cnf) in auto mode
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server-5.6.
(Reading database ... 210386 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-5.6_5.6.28-0ubuntu0.15.10.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server-5.6 (5.6.28-0ubuntu0.15.10.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server_5.6.28-0ubuntu0.15.10.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server (5.6.28-0ubuntu0.15.10.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.4-1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (225-1ubuntu9) ...
Setting up libmysqlclient18:amd64 (5.6.28-0ubuntu0.15.10.1) ...
Setting up libdbd-mysql-perl (4.028-2) ...
Setting up mysql-client-5.6 (5.6.28-0ubuntu0.15.10.1) ...
Setting up mysql-server-5.6 (5.6.28-0ubuntu0.15.10.1) ...
update-alternatives: using /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf to provide /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my.cnf) in auto mode
2016-03-05 14:32:13 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2016-03-05 14:32:13 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.6.28-0ubuntu0.15.10.1) starting as process 8166 ...
Job for mysql.service failed because a timeout was exceeded. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.6 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.6; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.6 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.21-0ubuntu4.1) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (225-1ubuntu9) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.6
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

After that I run the command mysql and I got this message error:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

I tried a lot of other suggetions from stackoverflow and other forums, but none of them are working. Can you help me with this ? thx

Comment: The command `sudo apt-get install mysql-service` gives me an error `Unable to locate package mysql-service` under Ubuntu 15.04